# How to make fmap rewrite rules fire?

Tags: haskell

Simple question: Why doesn't this trigger the rewrite rule?

```
{-# RULES "fmap/fmap" forall f g xs. fmap f (fmap g xs) = fmap (f.g) xs #-}

main = do
  txt <- fmap head (fmap words (readFile "foo.txt"))
  print txt
```

Now I wanted to write that extracting `fun` triggers the rule because it did in a previous test ... not this time.

```
{-# RULES "fmap/fmap" forall f g xs. fmap f (fmap g xs) = fmap (f.g) xs #-}

fun f g xs = fmap f (fmap g xs)

main = do
  txt <- fun (drop 1) words (readFile "foo.txt")
  print txt
```

Until I by chance added a module name:

```
module Main where

{-# RULES "fmap/fmap" forall f g xs. fmap f (fmap g xs) = fmap (f.g) xs #-}

fun f g xs = fmap f (fmap g xs)

main = do
  txt <- fun head words (readFile "foo.txt")
  print txt
```

Now it still doesn't work if I just write out the function application in the main function.

To sum it up:

- `txt <- fmap head (fmap words (readFile "foo"))` doesn't work
- `txt <- fun head words (readFile "foo")` doesn't work
- `txt <- fun head words (readFile "foo")` *plus module* works
- `fun f g xs = fmap f . fmap g $ xs` *plus module* doesn't work
- `fun f g xs = f <$> (g <$> xs)` *plus module* does work (but fires later)

All of this was done by calling `ghc --make -O2 -ddump-rule-firings Main.hs`. Sample output:

```
# ghc --make -O2 -ddump-rule-firings Main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Rule fired: fmap/fmap
Rule fired: unpack
Rule fired: Class op >>=
Rule fired: Class op fmap
Rule fired: Class op fmap
Rule fired: Class op show
Rule fired: Class op showList
Rule fired: unpack-list
Linking Main ...
```

Comment: Just as a side question: Does anyone know what these `Class op` rules are? Searching for them I haven't been able to find out. Apart from that: `rewrite-rules` tag? Doesn't seem common enough to justify its creation thou.

Comment: The `Class op` rules are created by GHC for monomorphic occurances of overloaded functions. See `compiler/basicTypes/MkId.lhs` in GHC (search for `"Class op "`): _This is the built-in rule that goes `op (dfT d1 d2) --->  opT d1 d2`_

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given what @Cactus said, what I believe happens here is that the rule `Class op fmap` *replaces* your `fmap` with its [method definition for `IO`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/libraries/base-4.9.1.0/src/GHC-Base.html#line-1083):

```
instance  Functor IO where
    fmap f x = x >>= (pure . f)
```

If this happens everywhere, before your rule is triggered, then there will be no `fmap`s left in (GHC's internal representation of) your code for your own rule to trigger on.

GHC tries to specialize class methods when they are used at specific types, so if the monad `fmap` is used within is completely known, there *won't* be any generic `fmap` left once it is done specializing.

So the remaining question is, why *does* your rule fire when you provide a module header?

```
module Main where
```

The answer lies in how this is slightly different from the *default* module header that is used if you don't provide any:

```
module Main (main) where
```

Note that this explicitly exports *only* `main` from the module. Your version, with no export list, instead exports everything defined in the module, *both* `main` and `fun`.

When only `main` is exported, GHC can deduce that `fun` is used *only* internally in `main`, and inline it completely there, not bothering to make a standalone version. Then it notices that the `fmap`s are used only for `IO`, and specializes them.  Or possibly it does it in the opposite order, but the end result is the same.

When `fun` is also exported, GHC must assume that the users of your module might want to call it in any monad. Therefore GHC then compiles a standalone version of `fun` for a generic monad, which *does* keep `fmap` generic, and your rule is able to fire on this version.

However, even for the explicit `module` code, the `Class op fmap` rule fires *twice* when compiling, as if it is applied to two separate `fmap`s. I therefore suspect that even in this case, `fun` is inlined and specialized in `main` *before* your rule has simplified it to use just one `fmap`, so the inlined version used inside `main` *still* will not have had your rule applied to it.

Comment: Ah damn ... so my example was kind of pathological ... in the real code the data is only instance of `Functor` and nothing else. Great answer by the way. Clear and concise.

Comment: Just FYI, the link is dead (404).

Comment: @ThreeFx Gah, GHC's documentation links are not optimized for permanence... or for finding a permanent link if you want one. I've updated to a hopefully permanent link to the current version, managing to get a proper anchor in at the same time.